# Why is the matrix "mat" not modified here?

Tags: functions, function-construction

Why is the matrix `mat` not modified here?

I expected it changes with `list1` and `list2` so that
`mat[[list1[[i]]]] = refmat[[list2[[i]]]]` respectively.

And all these changes are written into `mat`.

(`mat`, `list`, `list2`, `refmat` are not fixed)

```
mat = {{11, 12, 13, 14, 15}, {21, 22, 23, 24, 25}, {31, 32, 33, 34,
    35}, {41, 42, 43, 44, 45}, {51, 52, 53, 54, 55}};
list1 = {{3, 3}, {3, 2}, {3, 1}, {2, 3}, {2, 2}, {2, 1}, {1, 3}, {1,
    2}, {1, 1}};
list2 = {{1, 1}, {1, 2}, {1, 3}, {2, 1}, {2, 2}, {2, 3}, {3, 1}, {3,
    2}, {3, 3}};
refmat = {{m, n, p}, {c, k, f}, {k, c, q}};
Thread[mat[[Sequence @@ #]] & /@ list1 =
   refmat[[Sequence @@ #]] & /@ list2];
mat
```

[image]

Comment: In 12.3 I get an error message, saying that `Map` is protected

Comment: Instead of ``Thread[...]``, use ``MapThread[(mat[[Sequence @@ #1]] =  refmat[[Sequence @@ #2]]) &, {list1, list2}]``.

Comment: Same error in `V12.0.0`

Comment: I got the error in 13 too.
@Domen interesting, why MapThread works while Thread does not work?

Comment: `ReplaceAll[(mat[[Sequence @@ #]] & /@ list1), 
 Thread[pos -> (refmat[[Sequence @@ #]] & /@ list2)]]` something like that? `pos` is defined as `pos = {33, 32, 31, 23, 22, 21, 13, 12, 11};`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would probaby build up my replacements as a standalone structure. We can get the new values with Extract:

```
Extract[refmat, list2]
(*{m, n, p, c, k, f, k, c, q}*)
```

Then we can put these into replacement rules with the positions from list1:

```
MapThread[Rule, {list1, Extract[refmat, list2]}]
(*{{3, 3} -> m, ... , {1, 1} -> q}*)
```

Then ReplacePart can generate the desired value to update mat with:

```
ReplacePart[mat, MapThread[Rule, {list1, Extract[refmat, list2]}]]
```

Of course, that doesn't change the value of mat, but we can do that easily:

```
mat = ReplacePart[mat, MapThread[Rule, {list1, Extract[refmat, list2]}]]
```

Answer (score 3):

Making my comment an answer. Similar in spirit to @lericr but I used [`Thread`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Thread.html)

```
mat = {{11, 12, 13, 14, 15}, {21, 22, 23, 24, 25}, {31, 32, 33, 34, 
    35}, {41, 42, 43, 44, 45}, {51, 52, 53, 54, 55}};
list1 = {{3, 3}, {3, 2}, {3, 1}, {2, 3}, {2, 2}, {2, 1}, {1, 3}, {1, 
    2}, {1, 1}};
list2 = {{1, 1}, {1, 2}, {1, 3}, {2, 1}, {2, 2}, {2, 3}, {3, 1}, {3, 
    2}, {3, 3}};
refmat = {{m, n, p}, {c, k, f}, {k, c, q}};
pos = {33, 32, 31, 23, 22, 21, 13, 12, 11};
ReplaceAll[mat, Thread[pos -> (refmat[[Sequence @@ #]] & /@ list2)]]
```

> [image: hana]